# What are some appealing iPad instruments?

Tags: audio-software

Are there any iPad instruments that require skill to play and feel like a genuinely appealing instrument in and of themselves, rather than being a lower-quality simulation of something else? For example, it does not seem to be common to train and practice performing on an on-screen iPad piano, but is there any iPad instrument which really is an instrument in its own right, that people develop skill in playing, and isn’t just a simulation of something else?